# Downloading a project from Overleaf doesn't use the default "fonts" folder

Tags: fonts, overleaf

I have created my Resume using [Russell's template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/russelresume/zqnypvvjsfvq) on Overleaf and I've made it in a way that there are no warnings or errors at all.

I've downloaded the project locally, installed `texlive-full` and changed the compiler to XelaTex but it doesn't find `fontAwesome`. The file is inside the `fonts` folder (which is mentioned in the code to be the fonts directory). I can install it in my system, but I get some warnings then. But my question is: why doesn't it work like it does on Overleaf?

Comment: have you tried downloading from here? https://github.com/themagicalmammal/Resume

Comment: @user574859 wanted to avoid this because I had already changed a few things on Overleaf, but the Github did show me the reason: Overleaf version imports `fontAwesome` while Github imports `fontAwesome5`. Now seems like it works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Changing `\RequirePackage{fontawesome}` to `\RequirePackage{fontawesome5}` seemed to fix it.

Comment: Good to know. I though both packages were available in TeX Live and MiKTeX… Anyway, welcome TeX.SE Stasky.